# how do you add the values of variables in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to add the values of variables on python but it doesn't seem to work.

I want to try and add the values of the variables together even if the value is either True or False: please - can anyone help?

```
final=0
print ("welcome to my binary converter")
print("first number is the smallest value")
print ("please enter a 0 or a 1 five times")

in1 = input("number 1 please")

if in1 == 1:
    final=final+1
elif in1 == 0:
    final=final+0
elif ValueError
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")

in2 = input("number 2 please")

if in2 == 1:
    final=final+2
elif in2 == 0:
    final=final+0
elif ValueError
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")

in3 = input("number 3 please")

if in3 == 1:
    final=final+4
elif in3 == 0:
    final=final+0
elif ValueError
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")

in4 = input("number 4 please")

if in4 == 1:
    final=final+8
elif in4 == 0:
    final=final+0
elif ValueError
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")

in5 = input("number 5 please")

if in5 == 1:
    final=final+16
elif in5 == 0:
    final=final+0
elif ValueError
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")
print(final)
```

And I have tried looking on this website, python books, help online, python teacher, etc.

Also, I have version 3.3.0 if that helps.

Jacob

> > > welcome to my binary converter

first number is the smallest value

please enter a 0 or a 1 five times

number 1 please1

please enter a 1 or a 0

number 2 please0

please enter a 1 or a 0

number 3 please0

please enter a 1 or a 0

number 4 please1

please enter a 1 or a 0

number 5 please1

please enter a 1 or a 0

0

it seems to not change the value of final

Comment: really? A tutorial not the way to go? http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: What do you mean "even if the value is true or false"? What code did you write to try to add the variables? What happened? What do you think should happen instead? Why do you think that should happen? What do you want the result to be when you "add true and false"? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add variables together if both variables are either an integer or a string, but not a boolean (well, you kinda can but it's not effective). For example:

```
>>> var = 1
>>> var2 = 4
>>> var + var2
5

>>> stringvar = 'Hello '
>>> stringvar2 = 'world.'
>>> stringvar + stringvar2
'Hello world.'

>>> boolean1 = True
>>> boolean2 = False
>>> boolean1 + boolean2
1
```

The reason that works is because:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

---

EDIT:

It seems you have added in more code, so I'll show you what you're doing wrong.

The reason you're getting a Syntax Error is because you have `elif ValueError`. This doesn't work. First, there isn't even a ValueError, there can't be as you have an input(). If you want to check whether a number is not 0 or 1, do this:

```
in1 = input("number 1 please")

if in1 == 1:
    final += 1 # I've also changed this. final += 1 is the same as final = final + 1
elif in1 == 0:
    final += 0
elif in1 != 1 or in1 != 0:
    print("please enter a 1 or a 0")
```

I highly suggest reading over some python tutorials. This is some basic syntax.

Comment: @user2007306 What error are you getting? It seems to be working fine for me python 2.7

Comment: Invalid Syntax is what i get and if it did work it wouldn't register the change to final if the input is 1 or 0 so it just prints 0 Jacob

Comment: @user2007306 I have edited my answer to show why the syntax error is appearing

Comment: @user2007306 This is a good website to learn python: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ Chapter 30 talks about elifs.